# How to resolve Nginx error nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server" in conf:1?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I changed the configuration of nginx, and then restarted nginx when the following error occurs.

```
[root@host ~]# nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "﻿server" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/vhost/www.xxx.com.conf:1
```

Here is my configuration. How do I solve the problem?

```
server {  
    server_name www.xxx.com xxx.com;  
    listen 80;
    listen     443;

          ssl        on;
          ssl_certificate         /data/https/domain.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key     /data/https/domain.key;

    root /data/wwwroot/www.xxx.com; 
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    #rewrite
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php$1 last;
    }

location ~ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      include proxy.conf;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
      #allow 127.0.0.1;
     # deny all;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #fastcgi_pass remote_php_ip: 9000;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1: 9000; 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|flv|mp4|ico)$ {
      expires 30d;
      access_log off;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
      expires 7d;
      access_log off;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
    }
    access_log off;

}
```

Next, I used the-t test, and the result was like this.

```
[root@host ~]# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "﻿server" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/vhost/www.xxx.com.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

I just added the reverse proxy code and uploaded it to the server. 
This part of the code can not be deleted, do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Usually it's because of directive hierarchical rules like location must inside server blocks, etc. I would try it from a simple block first to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, is windows notepad saved using BOM format, using vscode to re-select no bom format UTF-8.